# How to make sequence based function faster in numpy?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, for-loop, vectorization

Considering a function below:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones(16).reshape(4,4)

def fn(a):
    b = np.array(a)
    for i in range(b.shape[0]):
        for j in range(b.shape[1] - 1):
            b[i][j+1] += b[i][j]
    return b

print(fn(a))
```

That is, for a general function that calculates `t+1` based on `t` in an array, can I make this faster? I'm aware there's a `np.vectorize` but not seeming appropriate for this case.

Comment: `vectorize` doesn't promise performance, even where it does work.

Comment: @hpaulj I tested a for-loop on 2d array, 1. loop i,j for both dimensions and calculate in-place 2. define a vectorized function and call `v_fn(arr)`, the second solution is 2x faster.

Comment: I was specifically referring to the `np.vectorize` function, not the general concept of `vectorization`.  Clearly in this case you don't need to iterate on the `i` dimension.  The `j` dimension needs something like a `ufunc.accumulate`, or `numba` to gain much speed.

Comment: @hpaulj the "vectorized function" is implemented with `np.vectorize`. A dumb example is `fn = lambda x: x*x`, with `v_fn = np.vectorize(fn)`. It's indeed faster than an embedded loop. But I've got your idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cumsum` I think that would be helpful.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a = np.ones(16).reshape(4,4)
df =pd.DataFrame(a)
df.cumsum(axis=1)
```

Or you can use `np.cumsum()`:

```
np.cumsum(a,axis=1)
```

Comment: Is there a more general solution? If the function is not doing cumulative sum. I found `numba` looks like what I'm asking for but never used it.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to reduce the two `for` loops to one `for` loop with little bit of copying overhead in addition.

```
In [86]: a 
Out[86]: 
array([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.]])

In [87]: b = a.copy() 

In [88]: for col in range(b.shape[1]-1): 
    ...:     b[:, col+1] = np.sum(a[:, :col+2], axis=1) 

In [89]: b
Out[89]: 
array([[1., 2., 3., 4.],
       [1., 2., 3., 4.],
       [1., 2., 3., 4.],
       [1., 2., 3., 4.]])
```

To make this work for a *generic function*, you can look for an equivalent function in numpy or implement one using numpy operations (vectorized one). For the example you provided, I just used `numpy.sum()` that does the job for us.

In terms of performance, this approach would be much better than operating using two `for` loops at the indices level, particularly for larger arrays. In the approach I used above, we work with slices of columns.

---

Here are the timings which suggest more than **3X speedup** over native python implementation.

---

Native Python:

```
def fn(a):
    b = np.array(a)
    for i in range(b.shape[0]):
        for j in range(b.shape[1] - 1):
            b[i][j+1] += b[i][j]
    return b
```

---

Slightly vectorized:

```
In [104]: def slightly_vectorized(b): 
     ...:     for col in range(b.shape[1]-1): 
     ...:         b[:, col+1] = np.sum(a[:, :col+2], axis=1) 
     ...:     return b
```

---

```
In [100]: a = np.ones(625).reshape(25, 25) 

In [101]: %timeit fn(a) 
303 µs ± 2.05 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [102]: b = a.copy() 

In [103]: %timeit slightly_vectorized(b) 
99.8 µs ± 501 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Not always you can find an equivalent function though.

Comment: @knh190 I agree! But almost all functions can be implemented using basic numpy ufuncs. You can then apply this newly implemented function

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called [accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import accumulate

def fn(a):
    acc = accumulate(a, lambda prev, row: prev + row)
    return np.array(list(acc))

a = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)
print(fn(a))
# [[ 0  1  2  3]
#  [ 4  6  8 10]
#  [12 15 18 21]
#  [24 28 32 36]]
```

There is no optimized accumulate function in numpy because it's not really possible to write accumulate in a way that's both performant & general. The python implementation is general, but will perform much like a hand coded lok.

To get optimal performance you'll probably need to find or write a low level implementation of the specific accumulate function that you need. You've already mentioned numba and you could also look into cython.